# Помогите пофиксить цикл в TelegramAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Цикл выполняется не по порядку, а до первой функции и как-только выполнится до функции цыкл решает завершится.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число:')     
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) 
    def handle_text(message): 
        try:
            number = int(message.text)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели число: {}'.format(number)) 
        except ValueError:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели некорректное число!')
        while number!=0:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число:')     
            @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) 
            def handle_text(message): 
                try:
                    number1 = int(message.text)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели число: {}'.format(number)) 
                except ValueError:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели некорректное число!')
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'ввёл: {number1}')
            number -= 1
```

Comment: опишите, как должен работать ваш бот, что вы хотите получить?

Comment: для какой цели в последней строке вашего кода вы вычитаете из переменной 1?

Comment: Я запускаю программу по команде /start. После этого я ввожу кол-во повторов скрипта, и он работает. После выполнения основного кол-ва действий я должен буду ввести число после чего программа вводить это число к себе, выводит его мне и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Откажитесь от циклов в таком решении, используйте метод `bot.register_next_step_chandler` для вызова функции.

```python
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    enter_number = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(enter_number, attempt1)


def attempt1(message):
    number = int(message.text)
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели число: {}'.format(number))
        while number != 0:
            enter_number = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите число:')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(enter_number, attempt2)
            number -= 1
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели некорректное число!')


def attempt2(message):
    number1 = int(message.text)
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели число: {}'.format(number1))
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели некорректное число!')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'ввёл: {number1}')
```

Насколько я понял, если пользователь вводит отличное от нуля число, то мы просим ещё раз ввести его число.

Сообщите, ту ли задачу выполняет мой код.

Comment: Вы поняли суть. Но не до конца. Мне по специфике моих задач нужно будет выполнять эту схему несколько раз. Когда-то может понадобится выполнить 1 раз, а когда-то потребуется и 20. Для этого и был цикл while который работал пока первоначально заданная переменная не будет приравниваться 0.

Comment: Пробуйте сейчас. Условие `if` было замененено на цикл `while`

Comment: При использовании вашей вариации программа работает следующим образом: https://imgur.com/a/FJWJvzo
Как это подразумевалось: https://imgur.com/a/N40ZkEj
Если вы заметили, то это ваш прошлый код. Но я думаю будет лучшей идеей взять первую функцию (attempt1) и направить её на задание количеств повторений, а уже вашу вторую функцию (attempt2) поместить в цикл что-б она повторялась то кол-во раз сколько было указано в первой функции (attempt1). Это реализуемая идея?

Comment: Есть контакты для связи, Discord, например?

Comment: Да, конечно. ДС: klaytons